# Replace [ ] bracket in a string

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, replace

I have a string that includes brackets, `[]`, around a number. Since this string represents my column names for a SQL database I need to remove/replace them.
So far I do it in the following way:

```
if (stringWithBracket.Contains("[0]"))
   noBracket = data.Replace("[0]", "0");
if (stringWithBracket.Contains("[1]"))
   noBracket = data.Replace("[1]", "1");
if (stringWithBracket.Contains("[2]"))
   noBracket = data.Replace("[2]", "2");
if (stringWithBracket.Contains("[n]"))
   noBracket = data.Replace("[n]", "n");
```

It works fine, but it looks ugly for me since I have to do that for [1] to [20].

Is there a way to implement this "nicer" which means with less code for me?

Comment: Are brackets also around something different than a number and you wish to keep them in that case?

Comment: You can use a regex to match only the specific pattern eg: `\[\(d+)\]`, then replace the matches with their contents. The parentheses are used to extract the content

Comment: BTW what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? How did bracketed number end up in a SQL statement, although they aren't column names? Are they placeholders for values or parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace` to ensure to only extract the numbers:

```
var pattern = @"\[(\d+)\]";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(stringWithBracket, pattern, "$1");
```

Comment: Why the loop?? A single execution will replace all bracketed numbers with their contents

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Depending on his requirements, I agree with you. I will change that part. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Forlan07: Thank you very much. It works perfect. Its exactly what i was looking for. I think i will have to spend some time with REGEX.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you want to remove all brackets:

```
data = data.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty);
```

Comment: This will remove all brackets, not just those around numbers

Comment: This is Nice! Worked just perfect.

Answer (score 3):

So you basicaly want a loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
    noBracket = data.Replace(String.Format("[{0}]", i), i);
}
```

Comment: You do not have to check if the bracket actual is contained in the string, you may just call replace in any case. However cool answer.

Comment: after extensivly scratching my chin I must admit: you're right! I will edit my answer.

Comment: This will create quite a few temporary strings in a lot of iterations, is limited by the loop's limits, and may not even find the proper numbers, eg if there are just two numbers named `[100],[200]`. A Regex on the other hand will create only the final string in a single operation and work with any number.

Comment: He said, he needed 1 to 20.

Answer (score 3):

This is the kind of thing that regular expressions are good at:

```
noBracket = Regex.Replace(stringWithBracket, @"\[(\d+\)]", "$1")
```

It matches a `[` (needs escaping as an opening bracket normally starts a character group), followed by one or more digits, followed by a closing bracket. The digits are captured (the parentheses) so it can be used in the substitution expression.

This replaces all occurrences in the string, to replace only the first would require a more complex regex that only matches once.

Comment: Wouldn´t `$0`return the whole string instead of the actual matching group?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes. Typo... fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
   string input="ab[test test}" 
   input = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\[|\]|\{|\}|\(|\)|\/|\\|\'|\.)", "");
   result= "abtest test"
```

Comment: While this code-only answer might be a valid solution to the original problem, it's not very helpful to other users viewing without any context of what your code is doing or how it is supposed to answer the original question.

Comment: An explanation would be in order.